# SQL queries do not currently support returning aliases

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hibernate, grails, hql

I have this raw sql that I am trying to run on grails

```
final session = sessionFactory.currentSession;
final  String query  = 'select count(A.*)  from Artifact as A LEFT JOIN classification as C on (A.id=C.artifact_id) where C.id IS NULL OR C.active=0';
final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);

def totalunclass =  sqlQuery.with {
                        addEntity(Artifact);                                        
                                }
```

But I am getting the error `Message: SQL queries do not currently support returning aliases`
I tried another method but failed there too achieve the result click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786193/hql-query-not-working-same-as-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query line to look like this

```
 final  String query  = 'select count(*)  from Artifact A LEFT JOIN classification C on (A.id=C.artifact_id) where C.id IS NULL OR C.active=0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remove aliases:

```
final session = sessionFactory.currentSession;
final  String query  = 'select count(Artifact.*)  from Artifact LEFT JOIN classification on (Artifact.id=classification.artifact_id) where classification.id IS NULL OR classification.active=0';
final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);

def totalunclass =  sqlQuery.with {
                    addEntity(Artifact);                                        
                            }
```